# How to run MU ONLINE?

Tags: wine

hi i am new in ubuntu still. i want to run mu online it is just 1 game with i play, but still can not run it. i downloaded wine program, but it looks that i need to download more or to do something. when i go to webzen page and click start game they offer me download webzen game starter. i downloaded it and instaled, but whne i press again start game it sed that i must download webzen game starter again. =( can somene help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true), Mu Online [does not work with Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1873), and thus cannot be run in Ubuntu. The [version of Wine tested](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23704) is slightly lower than the version currently [provided in Ubuntu 11.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.3), so that is slightly encouraging, but only very slightly--there is no reason to think anything has changed to make running it possible.

While you probably won't be able to get it to work, I recommend trying the latest beta, which is provided by [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa), which you can use by following [these instructions](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).